# Word meaning "honorably accepted into group"

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word of positive sentiment that conveys something being purposefully or honorably added to a group, especially a person.

After years of loyal knightship, he was finally _______ into the King's inner circle.

Close but doesn't capture the idea of being honored: selected, welcomed, included, consolidated, assimilated.

Comment: "Inducted" generally means being added to a group with some degree of ceremony.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[induct](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/induct)**:

> 1 :  to put in formal possession (as of a benefice or office) :
> install -- *was inducted as president of the college*
>
> 2 a :  to admit as a member -- *inducted into a scholastic society*
>
> b :  introduce, initiate
>
> c :  to enroll for military training or service (as
> under a selective service act)

Comment: Oh man I kept dancing around 'indict' and couldn't figure out why. That's spot on. This deserves acceptance for now. Hope that doesn't dissuade people posting more options..